# Интеграл в Visual Basic

Tags: visual-basic

Подскажите как или дайте литературу, с которой можно понять, как написать программу в Visual Basic для вычисления интеграла методами левых и правых прямоугольников, трапеций и парабол.

Очень надо.

Заранее благодарю!

Answer (score 1):

Любые самоучитель по бейсику и учебник по вычматам.